# Angular 2 Route params validation

Tags: validation, angular

How can I validate Route params in Angular2?
For example, I have a route:

```
{path: 'artist/:id', component: ArtistInfoComponent}
```

All I want is to check if parameter `id` is a valid number and if so, just show the component. Otherwise show a page with error message.

I found Route Guards in Angular 2 but I think this isn't the best way to do validation because I can have many different params for different pages and writing individual Route Guard for all these pages isn't what I want.

Is there a possibility to specify a regex for each route parameter?

**UPD: Maybe there is a way to do a validation on query params? I mean  if I have such url: `/search?q=blablabla&page=2` how can I check if the parameter `page` is valid? Is there a way to do it without Guards?**

Comment: Not much help from here, but a quick google gave this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12442 seems like isn't able to use regex for now (??) unless you find some info on that mysterious `urlMatcher` that is mentioned. But as said, I don't know, just found this page :)

Answer (score 4):

Guards are the way to go, you could put validation configuration into `data` section of the route and create reusable guard to validate parameters based on this configuration.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks

Comment: Ok, but maybe there is a way to do a validation on query params? I mean  if I have such url: `/search?q=blablabla&page=2` how can I check if the parameter `page` is valid? Is there a way to do it without Guards?

Comment: Router is responsible for handling location changes, so it is the right place to do validation. Also you could validate params in your component and manually redirect using router in case parameter is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

By using **ActivatedRoute** service you can get the param and match the param in the lists of ids you have. If matches then show the details else show error message.

exammple:

step 1: Inject(pass) ActivatedRoute in component constructor

```
constructor(private activtedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}
```

step 2:

```
    constructor(private activtedRoute: ActivatedRoute){
     this.activtedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
          const routeIdParam = params.get('id');
          if(this.validateId(routeIdParam)){
             // code to display info
                } else {
              // code to show error message!
             }   
           }

validateId(id): Boolean{
  return idArray.find(id); 
}
```